# Error with getopts in shell

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

I have a homework, write a program schedsim.sh with:

```
schedsim.sh [-h] [-c x] -i filename
```

In this:

`-h:` print username

`-c:` print x+1 (x is entered from keyboard), if don't enter x, print 1

`-i:` print size of filename, filename is a name of file that entered.

My code:

```
#i/bin/bash/

while getopts ":hc:i:" Option
do  
    case $Option in 
    h) 
    whoami 
    ;;
    c) a=$OPTARG
    if [ -z "$a" ]; then
        a=1
    else
        a=`expr $a + 1` 
    fi
    echo $a 
    ;;
    i) echo 'Size of file: Kylobytes' 
    ls -s $OPTARG 
    ;;
    *) echo 'sonething wrong' 
    ;;
    esac
done
```

However, when i call:

```
./schedsim.sh -c -i abc.txt
```

Error.

Sorry, my English is poor!

Comment: The first thing I would tell you is that your "shebang" on the first line is wrong.  It shouldn't be `#i...`  It should have an exclamation mark `!` instead of an `i`.  As in, it should be `#!...`.

Comment: **What** error are you getting when you call that? Do any of the options work? Is `getopts` itself failing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash Script with Parsing Argument in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826395/bash-script-with-parsing-argument-in-linux)

Comment: Your classmate asked this exact same question a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32826395/7552 -- if you both submit it, do I get extra credit? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you had the basic script quite close to working. I made a few changes such as adding a test for the existence of the user specified file before attempting to run `ls` on it and adding quotes around variables. I suggest asking your teacher how they would like you to calculate kilobytes for the area where you are using `ls`. `du` or `stat` may be better for this use case.

```
#!/bin/bash/

while getopts ":hc:i:" Option
do
    case "$Option" in
    h) whoami
       ;;
    c) a=$(( $OPTARG + 1 ))
       printf "$a\n"
       ;;
    i) if ! [ -f "$OPTARG" ]
       then printf "File does not exist\n"
       else printf "Size of file: Kylobytes: "
            ls -s "$OPTARG"
            printf "\n"
       fi
       ;;
    *) printf "something wrong\n"
       ;;
    esac
done
```

Another change I made was to use `$(())` shell arithmetic instead of `expr`. Generally if one needs more powerful mathematics than `$(())` can support they call out to `bc` (which supports floating point calculations) instead of `expr`.